# How to remove control option in datasheet column headers? MsAccess 365

Tags: ms-access-2016

MsAccess 97;2003 - OK

MsAccess 365 - NOK :(

this option's icon prevents of display titles of columns

[image: 365 vs 2003]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the form's property:

```
ShortcutMenu: False
```

[Form.ShortcutMenu property (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.Form.ShortcutMenu?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361)